# Exit not working properly

Tags: d3.js

Hello Im quite new to D3 and Im having trouble with exit function

I want to make some list and bars without using SVG and everything works like a charm.

I select the div and then append and enter my data to populate variuos divs.

```
var content = d3.select("#graph").selectAll("div")
        .data(bandMates)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .classed("member",true) //Div contenedor

        content
            .append("div")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        content
            .append("div")
            .style("height", "40px")
            .style("width", "0px")
            .style("background-color", "#ff9999")
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .style("width", function (d){ return d.songs + "px";});

        content
            .append("div")
            .text(function(d) { return "wrote " + d.songs + " songs!"; });
```

at the end of the process I include the `content.exit().remove();` function because I want to be able to update the number of songs with another function and then calling de draw() function again.

Firebug console is throwing me this error

```
content.exit is not a function
```

Am I missing something?
I went to Bostock's tutorials and everything seems to be ok.

I have done a JSFiddle to check out my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/9HTUM/

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle with three changes: http://jsfiddle.net/URpfB/

1) your initial selectAll selector needs to be more specific as there are many descendant divs in the page after your code runs once.  You need to distinguish between the top-most member divs and others by doing `selectAll('div.member')`

2) you need a data key function so d3 has more to go on than data length/position in order to determine when new data is added or old data is removed.  In your example, this would keep each div.member associated with a single member name: `data(bandMates, function(d){return d.name;})`

3) as Snoozer pointed out, you need to be more precise when assigning selections to variables.  You cannot exit() from enter() selections.

Comment: Love the Pete addition =) Thank you so much for the jsFiddle. It really improves Snoozer answer. enter() and exit() is still a stone in my shoes in my way to d3.

Answer (score 12):

You've defined content as:

```
var content = d3.select("#graph").selectAll("div")
    .data(bandMates)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .classed("member",true) //Div contenedor
```

So when you do `content.exit()`, it's like trying to do `d3.select("#graph").selectAll("div").data(bandMates).enter()..exit()`

You're calling exit on a selection you've already entered. If you define content instead as:

```
var content = d3.select("#graph").selectAll("div")
    .data(bandMates);
```

and then do `content.enter()....` in the 3rd line of code you shared in your answer, this error should go away.

`Enter()` and `exit()` are functions of a selection of data, so once you've called `enter()` you cannot later call `exit()` and have it be meaningful. `exit()` must be on the same data.

Comment: So enter and exit will never work on the same variable on this example in particular or as a general rule?

Comment: `enter()` and `exit()` will work on the same variable. What you did in your original code was essentially `mydata.enter().exit()`. You can't have both right after each other. You need `var x = d3.select("stuff").data(mydata)` and then separately do `x.enter()` and `x.exit()`. Ray's answer above does a much better job suggesting good data update practices

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you very much for your response. Im working on my code atm with that problem solved :)

Comment: @Snoozer When using this code, new divs are constantly created. Any ideas what's happening?

Comment: What do your data look like? I just tried it out in the fiddle from Ray's answer and got what looked to be 4 div's per item in the data

Answer (score 1):

**Tree-only possible cause...**

This is not related to the OP's issue, but I found this SO question while researching it so adding it for the next passerby.

In my case the cleanup of a d3.layout.tree on collapse/expand was not happening because I was forgetting to set the "node" class on the nodes.  It would seem as if d3 trees require the node class attribute to be set.

did not work

```
<g transform="translate(20,20)">
    <circle style="fill: rgb(198, 219, 239);" r="8"></circle>
    <text style="fill-opacity: 1;" dx="15" dy="4" id="txt_SELF_SERVICE" class="text">Self Service</text>
</g>
```

worked

```
<g transform="translate(20,20)" class="node ">
    <circle style="fill: rgb(198, 219, 239);" r="8"></circle>
    <text style="fill-opacity: 1;" dx="15" dy="4" id="txt_SELF_SERVICE" class="text">Self Service</text>
</g>
```